# How to arrange my Data in NoSQL (Invoices)

Tags: couchdb, nosql

i'm walking my first steps with nosql databases, but so far my knowledge is very basic. I try to set up a database for a small invoice system.

In SQL i'd create 4 Tables: Products, Customers , Invoices, and a match table for Invoice and the produts.

But how to do this with nosql? Do i even build relations or just build 1 document for each invoice.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep in mind that NoSQL design is not only based on data structure but also strongly on data function. So you should first ask yourself what kind of queries you need to do over your data and take it from there.

First figure out how far you want to go with denormalization and aggregation. For instance: what sets of data will often require to query or update at once? And try to keep that to a single document even if it means duplicating data from other entities (i.e. Storing customer data along with the invoice data).

So ask yourself why you want to use non relational databases, and how will you use that data. Then decide which modeling techniques to apply and how far. The highly scalable blog has a great [article about NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) if you care to give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

> ... or just build 1 document for each invoice.

Yes, do that for the beginning. Imagine your data in the CouchDB as read-only copy of your data in the relational database. The docs are like the result of your SQL queries.

> Do i even build relations?

Of course you can, its the same as in your SQL tables. You including ids of foreign docs and name the property regarding to the relation you want to express e.g. `doc.customer_id` in an invoice doc can point to the `doc._id` of a customer doc.

Its helpful you imagine the CouchDB views as "relations" e.g. you can create a view called `InvoicesByCustomer` with the example above.

But summarized i would recommend to begin with the `1 document for each invoice.`-approach and follow @JavoSN hint ...

> So you should first ask yourself what kind of queries you need to do over your data and take it from there

... when you know that clearly its time to dig deeper into your possibilities of document designs.